# A good PCI Express Card WiFi and Bluetooth for Dell 9020 SFF that will work on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, bluetooth, dell

What is a good PCI Express Card WiFi and Bluetooth (optional) for Dell 9020 SFF that will work on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

I have the USB Dongle and having to use workarounds to make it work: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1885985

I'm not wanting to deal with this and just use a card link this:
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B071QZGWDB/ref=nav_timeline_asin?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071QZGWDB)

Does anyone know of a good PCI Express Card with both WiFi and Bluetooth (optional) that works with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Comment: Hardware recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: I'm just needing this one help here. Not gonna be mad at anyone. Just want to ask the community to see what they use that's been successful. Also, where is the hardware ask site? If there isn't one, why not have one?

Comment: I'm just voting to close this question as off-topic, because it really is off-topic. No offence. You can ask at ubuntuforums.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I kinda disagree, Ubuntu/linux is having tons of problems with wifi cards nowadays. Open drivers never work as well as proprietary drivers. But i can understand that the question is kinda polariazed.  @yanike you should try make this question more general, something like "what are wificards that are known to be fully working with ubuntu on your laptop?" and with fully i mean, with no weird errors in the journal or in the driver section of ubuntu updates.
I think this would be legit, and i would also be very interested in it (even if not for the same device)

Comment: @Pilot6 would you still downvote? I'm not here for a long time, so I understand I might be wrong

Comment: I would suggest an Intel and then I’d vote to close.

Comment: I've posted cards and my result with one below. Typing this using the new card now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching on Amazon, I've found that users had no issues out of the box with these PCI cards. The cards worked without installing drivers.

**Ubit WiFi Card plus Bluetooth:** (The one I bought)

I have tested this with my Dell 9020 SFF and it works out of the box :)

[https://www.amazon.com/Ubit-Wireless-Network-Adapter-PC%EF%BC%88WIE5300%EF%BC%89/dp/B07GQPNPXG/ref=pd_rhf_ee_p_img_1?_encoding=UTF8&refRID=WCMSCJ5B5ZC21KPY3A2N&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GQPNPXG)

**LinksTek Wireless N 600Mbps:**
[https://www.amazon.com/LinksTek-Wireless-Adapter-PCIE-Card-Wireless-PCIE-N600/dp/B07Q1JK6QH/ref=pd_rhf_ee_p_img_2?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=5BQ2GM90YRSRJSP2VDK7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Q1JK6QH)

**Cudy WE3000 AX 3000Mbps:**
[https://www.amazon.com/Cudy-WE3000-3000Mbps-Wireless-Bluetooth/dp/B082NZYDDM/ref=pd_rhf_ee_p_img_8?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=5BQ2GM90YRSRJSP2VDK7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B082NZYDDM)

**Ubit AC 1200Mbps Bluetooth:**
[https://www.amazon.com/inal%C3%A1mbrica-Bluetooth-Ultra-baja-latencia-integrado/dp/B07PMGJ9XY/ref=pd_rhf_ee_p_img_11?_encoding=UTF8&refRID=5BQ2GM90YRSRJSP2VDK7&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PMGJ9XY)

**EDUP AC1200Mbps PCIe:**
[https://www.amazon.com/EDUP-Wireless-AC1200Mbps-Bluetooth-Networking/dp/B07RXKGGTR/ref=pd_rhf_ee_p_img_12?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=5BQ2GM90YRSRJSP2VDK7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RXKGGTR)